# Debugging in Visual Studio. Step into expression

Tags: c++, c

I am using Visual studio 2010. I want to know is there any option in the VS debugger to step into an expression.
Example:

```
int a = 5, b = 255, c = 10;
int result;
result = a + b*c + a&b ;
```

To understand the operator precedence, I want to know which expression in the `result = a + b*c + a&b ;` is executed first and which expression next.

Is there any option to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Read Assembly code produced by compiler.

Comment: Precedence is strictly defined - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Make readable code, the person who end up using your code will agree. If you don't know the default order: SPECIFY IT using parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

try to put open and close parenthesis. it will execute first

result = (a + (b*c)) + a&b ;

Comment: Yes, but now you have specified the order. @Patil likes to know what is the order if just typed (without parentheses).

Comment: Yes but he said "Is there any other option to do that?" so it means it is not restricted to that code.

Comment: True, you can help yourself by specifying it.